# Как отобразить 5 блоков перевёрнутой пирамидой?

Tags: html, css

[image: Необходимый результат]

Нужно вот так. У меня нижние блоки выровнены по левому краю, а нужно по центру. Все 5 блоков находятся внутри одного.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wr1{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wr1 div{
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
 
.wr1 div:nth-child(4){
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.wr1 div:nth-child(5){
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wr1">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `-o-flex` - это вообще откуда? Никогда не видел информации, что это свойство с таким префиксом существует.

Comment: @Qwertiy эту тайну знает emmet ... :))

Comment: Спасибо! Вечно благодарен! Весь день мучался